# PHP cURL 400 ERROR The request could not be satisfied

Tags: php, api, curl, php-curl

I'm using the bandsintown API for a personal project and my php code results in an error:

```
400 ERROR The request could not be satisfied. Bad Request
```

for some queries. I'm not sure why, and would like some help in fixing it. Thanks!

This is my code right now:

```
$ch=curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://rest.bandsintown.com/artists/".$artist."/events?app_id=".$app_id);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

$headers=array();
$headers[]="Accept: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

This results in an error on a fair number of artists and I'm not sure why.

Examples of some of the artists where this results in an error are those like BØRNS, MØ (which have normal results through a regular cURL request)

```
curl -X GET "https://rest.bandsintown.com/artists/B%C3%98RNS/events?app_id=$app_id" -H  "accept: application/json"
```

which I initially thought might have something to do with the non-standard characters.

But what makes me think this is another issue is that Calvin Harris and other similar artists with standard lettering throw the same error (and they also work fine on a regular cURL request)

```
curl -X GET "https://rest.bandsintown.com/artists/Calvin%20Harris/events?app_id=$app_id" -H  "accept: application/json"
```

So, I think there might be something wrong with the way I made my php cURL.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably because you don't urlencode $artist and $app_id. for example, a space is supposed to be encoded with `+` or `%20`, `Ø` is `%C3%98`, and so on. use urlencode(), or if that doesn't work, use rawurlencode().

Comment: Thanks so much. I had already tried urlencode because I thought it may have been the issue with the BØRNS like artists with no success. rawurlencode did the trick though.

Comment: @pokemonjello well, strictly speaking, urlencode() doesn't follow the 
 specs, while rawurlencode is encoding it strictly to the specs (the specs say `encode spaces as %20`, but for some reason, most people/services use `+` instead of spaces)